# Solr 5.2.0 data import screen of admin UI doesn't load

Tags: solr, lucene, dataimporthandler

In the Solr admin UI, on clicking of Data import page nothing happens. On entering the url directly in browser Dataimport screen remains in the loading. 
Please see attached screenshot. Remaining screens of the core work without any problem.

What am i missing ? Would appreciate any suggestions.

*No errors* being reported in the solr logs on clicking of the page.
Solr Version: **5.2.0**

[image: Data import screenshot]

Comment: If you have ad blocking, try loading it without. Perhaps one of the internal URLs conflict.

Comment: Can you get a stack trace from the Solr server? Are there any JavaScript errors in the error console of the browser?

Comment: @AlexandreRafalovitch and Clemens Klein-Robbenhaar,
Thanks for taking time to help.
I could not get it work with 5.2.0 so moved over to version 5.3.0 and it is working fine now.